# How can I get to know constraint name (given by us) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
alter table tut ADD Constraint MyUniqueness unique (tutorial_title ) ;
desc tut;
```

here I am not getting constraint name i.e. "MyUniqueness"

Answer (score 0):

`DESCRIBE` doesn't show constraints. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tut;
```

Comment: I have posted the answer too, you can refer that

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer:

```
select * 
from information_schema.table_constraints 
where table_name = "table_Name";
```